# UINavigationController hava a gap on top

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I add a UINavigationController via code, but it leave a gap on top.. about 20 px..
[image]

It disappear if I switch to other tab and go back to this tab, but it can be seen about 0.2 sec before the NavBar move to right position..

I already search StackOverflow but I can't find the solution...

this is part of my code :

appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    .....
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[Tab1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab1" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[FreshEpisodeController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FreshEpisodeController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc3 = [[Tab3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Tab3" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc5 = [[DownloadListController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DownloadListController" bundle:nil];
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabHost alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc2, vc1, vc3, vc5, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    .....
}
```

Tab3.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [[self view] addSubview:mNavController.view];
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Collection List", @"Collection List");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

in Tab3.xib, I have a `UIView` and `UINavigationController` (mNavController)

The gap is not there if I set Tab3 to show at the first time (I put it at first tab) 
But if I put it to second tab, It showed if I switch to view Tab3.

Answer (score 1):

setting the **Under Top Bars** attribute as **unchecked** from *Attributes* section of *ViewController* might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

set "wantsFullScreenLayout" property to "YES" for your view controller

Comment: indeed it resolve the problem at first view... but if I switch to other tab and go back... the navBar is moved to 0,0 which is get under the status bar...

Comment: your tab bar presents new view on every tab. you need to set this property to all needed views, or to view, that holds this tab bar. Dont shure about app's window, but you may try to set this to it.

Answer (score 0):

try to do it like this

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [[self view] addSubview:mNavController.view];
        mNavController.view.frame = self.view.bounds; //here you assign the subView frame to fit superView area
        self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Collection List", @"Collection List");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the `UINavigationController (mNavController)` within `viewDidLoad` method, codes should be look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[self view] addSubview:mNavController.view];
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Collection List", @"Collection List");
    self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab3"];
}
```

Enjoy now.....

Comment: not really helped.. In fact, The icon and title on TabBar is not loaded... it showed after the tab is clicked